# PivotItem changed to Visible = True, but pivot table not updating accordingly

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

as title says. both the column fields and row fields must proceed by a month for each monthly updated version.

```
Sub SetDatesforAllPvt()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim ipvt As PivotTable
Dim isheet As Worksheet
Dim cutoffdate As Date

cutoffdate = DateSerial(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Slicers New").Range("E4").Value - 3, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Slicers New").Range("E7").Value + 1, 1)


'For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
 '   Set isheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i)
 Set isheet = ActiveSheet

    For j = 1 To isheet.PivotTables.Count
    Set ipvt = isheet.PivotTables(j)
    'ipvt.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
    'ipvt.RefreshTable

    With ipvt.PivotFields("IncurredM")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
        .ShowAllItems = True
        For k = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
            If .PivotItems(k) >= cutoffdate Then
                .PivotItems(k).Visible = True
            Else
                .PivotItems(k).Visible = False
            End If
        Next
       ' .Orientation = xlhiddenfield
      '  .Orientation = xlRowField


    End With
    With ipvt.PivotFields("Paid M")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
        .ShowAllItems = True
        For k = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
            If .PivotItems(k) >= cutoffdate Then
                .PivotItems(k).Visible = True
            Else
                .PivotItems(k).Visible = False
            End If
        Next
     '   .Orientation = xlhiddenfield
      '  .Orientation = xlColumnField

    End With

    Next
'Next

End Sub
```

For some reason, after running the above, when individuela fields are opened in Excel, the newest month has a check mark next to it, so it should be visible. However, the month is not included in both the column and row. I have to manually deselect, then select the month, then the pivot table updates correctly and displays the latest month. What am I doing wrong?

adding the refreshtable or pivotcache.refresh did not help either.

Additionally, there are about 40-50 tables all interconnected with different slicers. There are about 20 slicers. When this script is run through the many worksheets, this code takes an unbelievably long time (I haven't seen the end of completion yet). At the bottom of Excel, it says running slicer something. Any advice on this matter would also be very appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always do your select `true` loop and then do a select `false` loop.  The reason being that Excel does them one at a time and will not allow you to have nothing selected in a pivot table, it will error out (or what have you)

So:

```
Sub SetDatesforAllPvt()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim ipvt As PivotTable
Dim isheet As Worksheet
Dim cutoffdate As Date

cutoffdate = DateSerial(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Slicers New").Range("E4").Value - 3, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Slicers New").Range("E7").Value + 1, 1)

 Set isheet = ActiveSheet

    For j = 1 To isheet.PivotTables.Count
    Set ipvt = isheet.PivotTables(j)

    With ipvt.PivotFields("IncurredM")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
        .ShowAllItems = True
        For k = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
            If .PivotItems(k) >= cutoffdate Then
                .PivotItems(k).Visible = True
            End If
        Next

        For k = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
            If .PivotItems(k) < cutoffdate Then
                .PivotItems(k).Visible = False
            End If
        Next

    End With

    With ipvt.PivotFields("Paid M")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
        .ShowAllItems = True
        For k = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
            If .PivotItems(k) >= cutoffdate Then
                .PivotItems(k).Visible = True
            End If
        Next

        For k = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
            If .PivotItems(k) < cutoffdate Then
                .PivotItems(k).Visible = False
            End If
        Next

    End With

  Next

End Sub
```

This may or may not solve your problem, but it will mitigate future problems as well.

And to your question, maybe building in a `Activeworkbook.RefreshAll` would help.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found out there was date filter applied to all tables, which took me by surprise since I didn't set it. By removing the filter, I was able to make everything visible.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the length of time this is taking to execute, you should set the PivotTable's .ManualUpdate property to TRUE before your PivotItems loop, and set it back to FALSE again when you are done. This stops the PivotTable refreshing after each and every PivotItem change.

You should also first check whether the PivotItem.Visible status needs to change, because it takes far longer to change it than to check it. I have a post on this at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/

With regards to the Slicer issue, I have another post that covers this in passing: see http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2015/11/17/filtering-pivottables-with-vba-deselect-slicers-first/